# symplectic geometry: help showing the cotangent lift of an action to a symplectic manifold is a symplectic action

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, group-actions, symplectic-geometry, co-tangent-space

I am following da Silva's lectures on symplectic geometry.

She defines the lift of a diffeomorphism as follows:

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be $n$-dimensional manifolds with cotangent bundles $M_1=T^*X_1$ and $M_2=T^*X_2$ and suppose $f:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is a diffeomorphism.

Then the lift $f_\#:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ is defined

$$f_\#(p_1) = p_2 = (x_2, \xi_2) = (f(x_1), \xi_2)
$$
where $\xi_1 = (f_{x_1})^*\xi_2 = \xi_{2}\circ df_{x_1}$ and $\xi_2 \in (T^*X_2)_{f(x_1)}$

$f_\#\rvert_{T^*X_1}$ is therefore the inverse map of $(f_{x_1})^*$

and so $\xi_2 = [(f_{x_1})^*]^{-1}\xi_1 = (f^{-1}_{x_1})^*$

Now let $(M, \omega)$ be the symplectic manifold obtained by equipping the tangent bundle $M=T^*N$ with the canonical 2-form $\omega = \sum_i dx^i \wedge d\xi^i$ and let the Lie Group G act on N:
$$\psi: G \rightarrow \text{Diff(M)}, \quad g \rightarrow \psi_g \\
$$
I am trying to prove the contangent lift of the action is symplectic (and hamiltonian)

We must have $$(\psi_g)_\#(p) = (\psi_g)_\#(x, \xi) = (\psi_g(x), (\psi_g^{-1})^*(\xi)) = (\psi_g(x), (\psi_{g^{-1}})^*(\xi))
$$

This must preserve the symplectic form, i.e.
$$((f_\#)^*\omega)_p (u, v) = \omega_{f_\#(p)}(df_p(u), df_p(v))
$$

I am unsure what to do from here. I can see the symplectic form takes in two coordinates that transform in seemingly inverse ways. Could someone point me in the right direction ? It would also help if anyone spots any errors in the way I state the problem, I have studied physics so far and am slightly out my depth with the mathematics.

EDIT: Solution using tautological one-form (this method is in da Silva's notes)

We want to show $(f_\#)^*\alpha_2 = \alpha_1$

The tautological form on $M_1$, $M_2$ is defined:
$$(\alpha_1)_{p_1} = \pi^*_{p_1}\xi_1, \quad \quad (\alpha_2)_{p_2} = \pi^*_{p_2}\xi_2$$

So we have
$$\begin{align}(f_\#)^*_{p_1}(\alpha_2)_{p_2} &= (f_\#)^*_{p_1}\pi^*_{p_2}(\xi_2)] \\
&= (\pi_2 \circ f_\#)^*_{p_1} \xi_2 \\
&= (f \circ \pi_1)^*_{p_1} \xi_2 \quad\quad \text{(The lift is constructed as such)} \\
&= (\pi_1)^*_{p_1}f^*_{x_1}\xi_2 \\
&= (\pi_1)^*_{p_1}\xi_1 \quad\quad \text{(By definition of the lift)}\\
&= (\alpha_1)_{p_1}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $f_\#$ preserves the tautological form as well as $d\alpha_1$, the canonical 2-form which is symplectic on $M_1$

Therefore the lift of the diffeomorphism $\psi_g:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$ is:

$(\psi_\#)_g:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$

and it is a symplectomorphism.

The lift of the action $\psi_\#$ is therefore symplectic.

It can also be shown the action is hamiltonian. It seems obvious since we are preserving the tautological one-form, although I'm not sure on the proof.

Comment: I think it is somewhat less difficult to show that the cotangent lift of a diffeomorphism preserves the Tautological one form ($\Theta$ such that $\omega=-d\Theta$). This allows one to use some of the inherent properties of the one form rather than relying on coordinate calculations.

Comment: Thank you, I have added my solution using your method (from da Silva's notes). Do you have any advice on making it more rigorous, or extending the proof to stating the lift of the action is hamiltonian ?

Comment: The rigor of your proof looks just fine to me. To prove that the lift of a diffeomorphism is hamiltonian apply "Cartan's magic formula" to $\iota_{X_t}\omega=-\iota_{X_t}d\Theta$ where $X_t$ is the time dependent vector field associated to the set of diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Item (3) in page 56 of [my notes](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/symp_geo.pdf) might be helpful (the notes are still incomplete, I should finish them by the end of July).

Answer (score 1):

My own attempt attempt at an answer after reading the comments:

Proving that the lift of the flow of a vector field $V$ on $X_1$ is a hamiltonian vector field.

The flow of a vector field $V$ on a manifold $M$ is an action of the real numbers on the manifold: $f: \mathbb{R} \times M \rightarrow M$

There is a bijection between symplectic actions of $\mathbb{R}$ on $M$ and complete vector fields on $M$ (given by the flow of the vector field).

We have shown the lift of the flow $f_\#$ is a symplectic action on $M_1$. Let its associated vector field be $V_\#$.

$V_\#$ is hamiltonian if $ \iota_{V_\#} \omega$ is exact.

$$\iota_{V_\#} \omega = -\iota_{V_\#} d\alpha
$$
By Cartan's magic formula:
$$\iota_{V_\#} \omega = d\iota_{V_\#}\alpha - \mathcal{L}_{V_\#}\alpha = d\iota_{V_\#}\alpha
$$
Since $f_\#$ preserves the tautological form $\alpha$

$V_\#$ is therefore hamiltonian with hamiltonian function $H = \iota_{V_\#}\alpha$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general proof of your statement that actions of Lie groups lift to Hamiltonian actions (in your answer you only showed this for $\mathbb R$-actions).

If $G$ acts on $X$ from the left, there is an induced left action of $G$ on $M=T^*X$, given by
$$
g\cdot\eta=(\psi_{g^{-1}}){}^*\eta=\eta\circ d(\psi_{g^{-1}})_{gx}
$$
for all $\eta\in T_x^*X$; here we have denoted $\psi_g(x)=g\cdot x$. It's easy to see this is a left action, and we will denote it as  $\bar\psi_g(\eta)=g\cdot \eta$. Now this induced action preserves the tautological form, i.e. $(\bar\psi_g)^*\tau=\tau$ or more explicitly
$$
\tau_{g\cdot \eta}\circ d(\bar\psi_g)_\eta=\tau_\eta
$$
which stems from the fact that the following diagram commutes (you've basically shown this in your question):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
T^*X @>{\bar\psi_g}>> T^*X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
X @>{\psi_g}>> X
\end{CD}

To show that the action is moreover Hamiltonian, we need to come up with a momentum map, and the natural candidate is given by the dual of the "fundamental map" of the action of $G$ on $X$: recall that we have a linear map $\sigma\colon \mathfrak g\rightarrow \mathfrak X(X)$ which is given pointwise as
$$
\sigma(\xi)_x=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}\exp(t\xi)\cdot x.
$$
Taking the dual of this map, we obtain $\mu_x\colon T^*_xX\rightarrow \mathfrak g^*$, explicitly given as $\mu_x(\eta)(\xi)=\eta(\sigma(\xi)_x)$. These maps altogether define a map $\mu\colon T^*X\rightarrow \mathfrak g^*$. It is customary to denote for any $\xi\in\mathfrak g$ the function $\mu^\xi\in C^\infty(T^*X)$, $\mu^\xi(\eta)=\mu(\eta)(\xi).$

To check that this is indeed a moment map for the action, you now need to show two things:

- $d(\mu^\xi)_\eta(v)=\omega(\rho(\xi),v)$ for all $v\in T_\eta(T^*X)$. Here, $\rho\colon \mathfrak g\rightarrow \mathfrak X(T^*X)$ is the fundamental map of the induced action.
- Equivariance with respect to the coadjoint representation, i.e.
  $$
  \mu(g\cdot \eta)(\xi)=\mu(\eta)(\mathrm{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\xi).
  $$

The first one is a consequence of the fact that the fundamental vector fields $\rho(\xi)$ and $\sigma(\xi)$ are $\pi$-related for any $\xi\in\mathfrak g$, i.e. there holds $d\pi_\eta(\rho(\xi)_\eta)=\sigma(\xi)_{\pi(\eta)}$ for all $\eta\in T^*X$. Here, $\pi\colon T^*X\rightarrow X$ is the canonical projection. Hence:
$$
\tau_\eta(\rho(\xi)_\eta)=\eta\circ d\pi_\eta(\rho(\xi)_\eta)=\eta(\sigma(\xi)_{\pi(\eta)})=\mu^\xi(\eta).
$$
Using this with the magic formula as in your answer, gives the first point:
$$
\require{cancel}
\iota_{\rho(\xi)}\omega=-\iota_{\rho(\xi)}d\tau=d\iota_{\rho(\xi)}\tau-\cancel{\mathcal L_{\rho(\xi)}\tau}=d(\tau(\rho(\xi)))=d(\mu^\xi)
$$

The second one follows by a simple computation using the naturality of the exponential map $C_g\circ \exp=\exp\circ \mathrm{Ad}_g$ and our definition of the momentum map $\mu$.